# FontAwesome icons in Xamarin.IOS not showing up

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, font-awesome

I have looked at and tried the first Ten examples of how to accomplish this on google and none of them work. I was able to only get one FontAwesome icon to work and that was the glyph five icon and it still wont work. Has anyone here been able to get this to work recently and if not, are there any alternatives to FontAwesome? I dont realy want to use images because the scale doesnt look right when going from an iPhone 5 to an ipad pro.

Comment: On iOS you have to use "Real" name of font, not the filename. And `Iconize` is also a good choice. Refer to https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/86333/font-awesome-not-working-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this issue. Fortunately, I got the right result at last. Please follow the checklist below:

1. Make sure your icon exists in the font files. Some icons are only available in Solid font. Check it on the FontAwesome web site. Also, you can try to set the FontAttribute of the Label as "Bold".
2. Place the font files in the Resources folder, such as Resources\Font Awesome 5 Free-Solid-900.otf. Then add the section below into the info.plist:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
              <array>
                <string>Font Awesome 5 Brands-Regular-400.otf</string>
                <string>Font Awesome 5 Free-Regular-400.otf</string>
                <string>Font Awesome 5 Free-Solid-900.otf</string>
              </array>
```

3. Make sure you select the right font name, not the file name. You can define a style as shown below:

   ```
   <OnPlatform x:Key="FontAwesomeString" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
   <On Platform="iOS" Value="Font Awesome 5 Free" />
   <On Platform="Android" Value="Font Awesome 5 Free-Solid-900.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid" />
   <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/fonts/Font Awesome 5 Free-Solid-900.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free" />
   ```

So you can use the style like this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Icon}" FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                   Style="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" />
```

4. If you use it in XAML, use it like: Text="" Use &#x before the font code.
   If you use it in C# code, use it like: Text="\uf015"; Use \uf before the font code.
5. No need to "Copy to Output Directory". Just set the BuildAction as BundleResource.

Hope it would be helpful.